# Which scriptures describe the Dupahariya flower?

Tags: shiva, ayurveda

I was reading an ayurvedic book so i need to know about the flower Dupahariya .I can't tell you all the name of the book as shiva told not to tell anyone about this in that tantra.

What Hindu scriptures describe this plant/flower? And yes other names of that flower, viz., is it mentioned in Ayurvedic treatises or does it have synonyms mentioned in the Nighantus?

Comment: This might help: [Mid-day flower](http://www.flowersofindia.net/catalog/slides/Midday%20Flower.html)

Comment: @Aman thanku very much aman but i am still not able to guess is it the Plant which has small small seeds in it's flower https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJ0Bpes2fog.

Comment: As far as I remember these flowers used to in my school's garden. It's @1:59 in the above video. Flower seems to be little bit rare these days.

Comment: Dupahariya is the name in Sanskrit? Btw is it related to Indrajal?

Comment: @Aman and Rickross it is related to ayurvedic treatment.I have tried some combinations from that book and need to say it's miraculous book.

Comment: Oh that's good to know @PravinRGMishra

Comment: There is a [biology.se] which accept identification of flowers and plants under the tag species identification. This is not really a Hinduism question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It most probably corresponds to Pentapetes phoenicea belonging to the Malvaceae family. It is variously mentioned as Bandhūka, Bandhujiva or Bandhujīvaka or even Jayasumana.

Rājanighaṇṭu: Bandhūka (hindi Guldupahariā or Dopahariyā) has mention in the Rājanighaṇṭu (tenth chapter). It is described as follows:

> Sanskrit Synonyms: Bandhūka, Bandhujīva, Oṣṭhapuṣpa, Arkavallabha, Madhyandina, Raktapuṣpa, Rāgapuṣpa, Haripriya
>
> Translation of verses (Āyurvedic Properties and Types) by Dr. Satish Chandra Sankhyadhar:
>
> “Bandhūka presents four varieties based on the colours of its flowers viz., black, white, yellow and red. It is a good antipyretic rug, besides being used in preventing bad celestial effects and the effects of bad spirits. It is said to be employed in the prayers of the Sun God [Savitṛ], to please him”.
>
> Rājanighaṇṭu, 10.117-118
>
> (the commentary mentions some additional comparative notes and cross references)

The plant species Pentapetes phoenicea is mentioned as Bandhūka in the Parama Samhita where it's use in worship is prohibited even on occassions of emergency:

> 42-44. Flowers not to be used even on occasions of emergency: These are ... Bandhūka (Pentapetes phoenicea, Tam. Mechi tilakam)...
>
> 45-47. Those mentioned above among tree-and creeper-flowers should be avoided under all circumstances...
>
> [(source)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/parama-samhita/d/doc242569.html)

Another reference to Bandhūka is found in the Lalita-sahasranama, in the 964th name:

> Bandhūka-kusuma-prakkhyā बन्धूक-कुसुम-प्रक्ख्या (964)
>
> Bandhūka is a tree (Pentapetes Phoenicea) whose flower is yellowish red in colour.  This flower is said to be very bright and tender.  She is compared to this flower.
>
> [(source)](https://www.manblunder.com/articlesview/lalitha-sahasranamam-meaning-960-967/)

Comment: @Gabe i have upvoted because came to know it is mentioned in samhita and Lalita-sahasranama.Thanku